# Order by one column if the other is empty for each field

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have two tables: a Topics tables and a joined Comments tables, both with timestamp columns.  I would like to order the topics list so that topics with the most recent comment are at the top.  However, if a topic has no comments, I want it to be sorted by the date it was created. 
In other words I'm trying to order it so that the topics are sorted by the date they were created *only* if they have no comments – basically like any forum. For example if topic A (empty) was created *after* topic B (not empty) but topic B has a reply that was most recent the order should be B, A. I don't want all the empty topics at the top if they're old or at the bottom if they're new.

I tried the IF ISNULL statement but it applies to the entire column and not each individual row so I end up with the empty threads either stuck at the top or bottom of the feed.

I'm guessing I'd have to construct a virtual column with only the most recent comment from each topic...?

Here's the full statement:

```
SELECT
  $showbody,
  Topics.Title,
  Topics.id AS tID,
  Topics.Timestamp,
  Topics.MemberID,
  Users.id,
  Users.FirstName,
  Users.LastName,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Tags.Keywords SEPARATOR ', ') AS Tags,
  COUNT(Comments.id) AS NumberOfComments,
  (
    SELECT COUNT(Comments.id)
    FROM Comments
      LEFT JOIN Views ON Comments.TopicID = Views.TopicID
    WHERE Comments.Timestamp > Views.Visited
  ) AS NewComments
FROM Topics 
  LEFT JOIN Users ON Topics.MemberID = Users.ID 
  LEFT JOIN Comments ON Topics.id = Comments.TopicID 
  LEFT JOIN Tags ON Topics.id = Tags.TopicID 
WHERE Topics.id NOT IN (
  SELECT Tags.TopicID
  FROM Tags
  WHERE Keywords IN (
    SELECT Tag
    FROM Filters
    WHERE MemberID = '$_SESSION[SESS_MEMBER_ID]'
  )
  GROUP BY Tags.TopicID
) 
GROUP BY Topics.id 
ORDER BY Comments.Timestamp, Topics.Timestamp DESC LIMIT $plim
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you paste your code here ?

Comment: please show the actual SQL statement...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution 1 (demo):

```
-- Test initialization
CREATE TABLE Question
(
     QuestionID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
    ,Content NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
    ,CreateDate DATETIME NOT NULL -- DEFAULT NOW()
);

CREATE TABLE QuestionComment
(
     QuestionCommentID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
    ,QuestionID INT NOT NULL REFERENCES Question(QuestionID)
    ,Content NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
    ,CreateDate DATETIME NOT NULL -- DEFAULT NOW()
);

INSERT  Question(Content, CreateDate)
SELECT  'Question 1','2011-01-01 01:00:00'
UNION ALL
SELECT  'Question 2','2011-01-01 02:00:00'
UNION ALL
SELECT  'Question 3','2011-01-01 03:00:00';

INSERT  QuestionComment(QuestionID, Content, CreateDate)
SELECT  1,'Comment 1.1','2011-01-01 01:30:00'
UNION ALL
SELECT  2,'Comment 2.1','2011-01-01 02:30:00'
UNION ALL
SELECT  1,'Comment 1.2','2011-01-01 02:40:00'
UNION ALL
SELECT  2,'Comment 2.2','2011-01-01 02:30:00'
UNION ALL
SELECT  1,'Comment 1.3','2011-01-01 03:30:00';
-- End of Test initialization

-- Solution
SELECT  *
FROM    Question q
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT  qc.QuestionID, MAX(qc.CreateDate) LastCreateDate
    FROM    QuestionComment qc
    GROUP BY qc.QuestionID
) qc    ON q.QuestionID=qc.QuestionID
ORDER BY IFNULL(qc.LastCreateDate, q.CreateDate) ASC;
-- End of Solution

-- By, by
DROP TABLE QuestionComment;
DROP TABLE Question;
```

Results:

```
2   Question 2  2011-01-01 02:00:00 2   2011-01-01 02:30:00
3   Question 3  2011-01-01 03:00:00     
1   Question 1  2011-01-01 01:00:00 1   2011-01-01 03:30:00
```

Solution 2:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    Topics t
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT  c.TopicID, MAX(Timestamp) LastTimestamp
    FROM    Comments c
    GROUP BY c.TopicID 
) c ON t.id = c.TopicID 
ORDER BY IFNULL(c.LastTimestamp, t.Timestamp) ASC
```

Comment: Using 'ORDER BY IFNULL(MAX(Comments.Timestamp), Topics.Timestamp) ASC' I keep getting the empty topics at the top and topics with newer comments at the bottom.  Have I done something incorrect?

Comment: This behavior is normal because `MAX(Comments.Timestamp)` (for topics without comments) will be `NULL` and `NULL`s are displayed first. Try to use my method.

Comment: Look at my last example regarding `NULL`s sorting order.

Comment: I'm trying to order it so that the topics are ordered by the date they were created only if they have no comments – basically like any forum.  For example if topic A (empty) was created after topic B (not empty) but topic B has a reply that was most recent the order should be B, A.  I don't want all the empty topics at the top if they're old.

Is 'ORDER BY IFNULL(MAX(Comments.Timestamp), Topics.Timestamp) ASC' not synonymous with what you wrote?

Thanks

Comment: Miles: take a look at the second solution.

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks so much for the help.  It was the subquery after the left join that did it - I assumed that wasn't needed at first. Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

Use a left join for the comments, group on the topics, use `max` to get the time of the last comment, and use coalesce (or isnull) to sort on the comment date if it's there and the creation date otherwise.

Example:

```
select t.Title, t.CreatedDate, max(c.CreatedDate) as LastComment
from Topics t
left join Comment c on c.TopicId = t.TopicId
group by t.Title, t.CreatedDate
order by coalesce(max(c.CreatedDate), t.CreatedDate) desc
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to work, the empty threads stay at the top and the threads with the newest comments at the bottom

Comment: @Miles: I forgot to put `desc` in the `order by`.

Comment: That will just cause all the empty threads to collect at the bottom, which in some ways is worse; if someone creates a topic it will be put on the last page where no one will ever see it.  Conversely if it is in ascending the old topics that no one replied to will stay right at the top instead of drifting to the bottom of the pile.  I'm trying to sort the threads on activity, not on whether or not they have replies.

Comment: @Miles: That is what this query does. It will use the latest comment date if there are comments in the thread, and the thread creation date it there are no comments. If it doesn't work, check that you have implemented it correctly.